# Select table and join count conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Sorry if my question's title is unclear. I'll try clarify it.

I have two tables: company and coupon. I need to get data from company with LIKE query and also join count of coupons that belong to these company. But the problem is that only coupons where some fields are > NOW() and > 0 should be counted. Other companies whose coupons are expired should have null. Also they should be ordered by several columns of coupon table.
I'm using MariaDB.

coupon table looks like this:

```
id    name    company_id   exp_data   valid_date   available   sold   views
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

company table looks like this:

```
id   name    logo
-----------------
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT company.name,
       coupon.amount
FROM company
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT company.name,
          COUNT(coupon.id) AS amount
   FROM company
   LEFT JOIN coupon ON company.id = coupon.company_id
   WHERE coupon.exp_date > NOW()
     AND coupon.valid_date > NOW()
     AND coupon.available > 0
   ORDER BY coupon.available,
            coupon.sold,
            coupon.views) coupon ON coupon.company_id = company.id
WHERE company.name LIKE '%s%'
```

This is the error I got:

```
SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'coupon.company_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Irrespective of the solution, the error is obvious as coupon.company_id is not part of the select clause.

Comment: Be aware that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: Coupon table do not have column called company_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I formatted your sql query properly so you can actually see it.

```
SELECT company.name, coupon.amount 
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT company.name, COUNT(coupon.id) AS amount 
    FROM company 
    LEFT JOIN coupon ON company.id = coupon.company_id 
    WHERE coupon.exp_date > NOW() 
    AND coupon.valid_date > NOW() 
    AND coupon.available > 0 
    ORDER BY coupon.available, coupon.sold, coupon.views
) coupon ON coupon.company_id = company.id 
WHERE company.name LIKE '%s%'
```

Order by should be outside of the subselect.
Your're left joining Company on Company and left joining the coupon on that. That seems wrong. Also company.id is not in the subselect and can thus not be joined on.

this should be your solution in pseudocode.
Please next time format your sql query so it is not just one continuous line.

```
select company.name, count(coupon.id) as coupon_amount
from company
left join (
    select * from coupons
    where (coupon not expired)
) as coupon
on coupon.company_id = company.id
where company.name like 'xxx'
order by (desired order)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for bad formatting. You're the best! :)

Comment: Always happy to help. Tipp: if you select a block of text and press CTRL + K it autoformats it as code. This helps in copying codeblocks. Also good formating makes writing and maintaining SQL Querys just so much easier